# How can I found out other computers' NetBIOS name using Wireshark?

Tags: home-networking, wireshark, netbios

I filtered captured packets like `nbns`, but NBNS packet format is confusing me.

Quoting Wireshark Wiki:

```
NetBIOS Name Service
    Transaction ID: 0xe17b
    Flags: 0x0110 (Name query)
        0... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a query
        .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Name query (0)
        .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
        .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
        .... .... ...1 .... = Broadcast: Broadcast packet
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        PSMTP.COM<00>: type NB, class IN
            Name: PSMTP.COM<00> (Workstation/Redirector)
            Type: NB
            Class: IN
```

What does `type` and `class` mean?

Is `PSMTP.COM` a NetBIOS-name? As it is not located in the same LAN as my PC, i think it is not.  But if i filter NBNS packets as `Source == *needed IP-adrress in the same LAN*`, would this field in the packet be a NetBIOS-name?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check a bit more into it as Wireshark also presents you data from the other layers.

As for this [the official RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1002.txt) which is referenced from the [WireShark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/NetBIOS/NBNS) probably has the information you want. Also the [WireShark database for display filters for NetBIOS Name Service](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/n/nbns.html) lists the flags themselves.

From the RFC:

```
 QUESTION_CLASS is defined as:
   Symbol      Value   Description:
   IN         0x0001   Internet class

 QUESTION_TYPE is defined as:
   Symbol      Value   Description:
   NB         0x0020   NetBIOS general Name Service Resource Record
   NBSTAT     0x0021   NetBIOS NODE STATUS Resource Record (See NODE
                       STATUS REQUEST)
```